# Save form as foreign key's object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

There is 2 models with a `ForeignKey` Relationship, `Profile` model and `Article` model, I would like to save the connected user as `profile.user` when an  `Article` object is created.

Here is the error I get with the code below :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

**models.py** :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)

class Gig(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Here is my **view** for where I want to save `profile.user`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = GigForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save()
        save_it.profile.user = request.user #error occured here.
        save_it.save()
        return redirect(reverse('own_gigs_details'))
else:
    form = GigForm()
```

**Forms.py**

```
class GigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gig
        fields = ['title', 'image', 'body', 'price']
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the `GigForm` please.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I don't think it has a lot to do with the GigForm but I updated it

Comment: Well, as far as I see, you're not creating `profile` which is an FK, so it's just None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create a Gig by saving the form, there is no profile linked to it (because it wasn't declared in your form). So, your error occurs because save_it.profile has no value.

I think you are trying to link a Gig to the Profile of the user logged in. To do this, I think you can do

```
save_it.profile = request.user.profile
save_it.save()
```

instead of assigning the user itself.

OneToOneField lets you reference objects in both directions. So you can do user.profile and profile.user.

Comment: I don't think I was clear with that last sentence. ForeignKey is definitely your best bet in the case of relating Gigs to Profile, as there can be many Gig instances relating to one profile. But when dealing with user and profile, this is a 1-to-1 mapping which is why you used a OneToOneField. It means you can reference each from the other... Good luck!

Comment: Oooh, makes sense now